# Почему в сафари не устанавливаются COOKIE?

Tags: cookie, safari

Вот такое условие в актуальной версии сафари на os X не срабатывает и всегда выводит то что после `else`, в других браузерах работает нормально

```
<?
    if (!empty($_COOKIE['userCityName'])){
        echo $_COOKIE['userCityName'];
    } else {
        echo "Иркутск";
    }
?>
```

Comment: PHP — серверный язык. Он никак не связан с версией браузера

Comment: Тем не менее я не могу понять, почему в других браузерах отрабатывает как надо

Comment: Может у вас идёт блокировка куки? Бывает что на предприятии не верно выставлены сайты "инфразоны". А если вы работаете через iframe  то нужно ещё добавить ключи разрешающие куки. Может по какой-то другой причине куки в safari не разрешены.

Comment: Нет, у меня на сайте используются 3 куки и отрабатывают как надо, я по ним часть контента фильтрую и редиректы делаю, а вот здесь на этом условии проблема
Куки полностью почистили, перезаписались, но выводит так же

Comment: как вы устанавливаете куку?

Comment: `var_dump($_COOKIE)` в студию